# JSON response cannot be seen

Tags: javascript, rest, cordova, google-cloud-vision

I have to make a cordova app where the user takes a photo and using cloud vision and rest api,to inspect the image taken. But no Json response nor error is being returned.

JavaScript- REST API call - pass base64 data returned from camera plugin

```
function callREST() {
    var _apiKey = "MYKEY"
    var _data = {
        requests: [
            {
            image: {
                content: imageData //base64 image string
            },
            features: [
            {
            type: "IMAGE_PROPERTIES"
            }
            ]
        }
            ]
        };
```

Process REST Call via the below outlined

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET", //GET, POST, PUT or DELETE
  url: "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate" + _apiKey, //INSERT URL!!
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(_data),
  success: restSuccess,
  error: restError
      });
  }
```

if success

```
function restSuccess(result) {
    console.log(result);
        console.log(responseJSON);
        getAllHighValues();
        var DominantColor = results;
        var data={referenceKey: DominantColor, color:HELPERRESULT.color,score: HELPERRESULT.score};

        saveData(data);
    }
```